# replace similar string in a text using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

we have a text like:

> this is a test :rep more text more more :rep2 another text text qweqweqwe.

or

> this is a test :rep:rep2 more text more more :rep2:rep another text text qweqweqwe. (without space)

we should replace :rep with TEXT1 and :rep2 with TEXT2.

problem:
when try to replace using something like:

```
rgobj = new RegExp(":rep","gi");
txt = txt.replace(rgobj,"TEXT1");

rgobj = new RegExp(":rep2","gi");
txt = txt.replace(rgobj,"TEXT2");
```

we get TEXT1 in both of them because :rep2 is similar with :rep and :rep proccess sooner.

Comment: Replacing ":rep\\b" would look for :rep followed by a word boundary (i.e. on its own)

Comment: Can you use " :rep " and " :rep2 " as regular expression instead ? I mean add spaces ? Or test rep2 before rep.

Comment: :rep maybe become just after :rep2 like this(these are smiley codes): this is a test :rep:rep2 more text more more :rep2:rep another text text qweqweqwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>If you require that `:rep` always end with a word boundary, make it explicit in the regex:</s>

```
new RegExp(":rep\\b","gi");
```

(If you don't require a word boundary, you can't distinguish what is meant by "hello I got :rep24 eggs" -- is that `:rep`, `:rep2`, or `:rep24`?)

**EDIT:**

Based on the new information that the match strings are *provided by the user*, the best solution is to sort the match strings by length and perform the replacements in that order. That way the longest strings get replaced first, eliminating the risk that the beginning of a long string will be partially replaced by a shorter substring match included in that long string. Thus, `:replongeststr` is replaced before `:replong` which is replaced before `:rep` .

Comment: What happens when you replace the word boundary?

Comment: @AndrewJackman Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. When you include the word boundary, `/:rep\b/` no longer matches `:rep2`, which is the desired goal.  The word boundary itself is a descritive feature of the string and does not get replaced, because it does not have a character representation in the string.

Comment: no these codes maybe :rep :xyz :yyz everything users sets. these are smiley codes.

Comment: Well, if them the user specifies a list of character sequences and their replacements, generally what you need to do is simply disallow the user from including any entries that are substrings of another entry on the list. This requirement changes the question substantially, and you should edit it to include the requirement that the `:rep` strings are provided by users.

Comment: I agree with @apsillers in the sorting, its the easiest way to ensure you aren't replacing anything incorrectly.

Comment: Edited my answer with a better solution.

Comment: very nice idea. I maybe do this or change code to place space at start and end of special-codes. anyway I select your idea as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is always consistent, replace `:rep2` before `:rep`.

Otherwise, you could search for `:rep\s`, searching for the space after the keyword.  Just make sure you replace the space as well.

Comment: no it is not and may contain as many as such string for replacement.

Comment: :rep maybe become just after :rep2 like this(these are smiley codes): this is a test :rep:rep2 more text more more :rep2:rep another text text qweqweqwe